# Completion Suggester in ElasticSearch On Existing Field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In my elasticsearch index, I have indexed a bunch of jobs. For simplicity, let's just say they are a bunch of Job Titles. When people are typing a job title into my search engine, I want to "Auto Complete" with possible matches.

I've investigated the Completion Suggester here : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

However all the examples I've found involve creating a new field on your index, and manually populating this field while indexing/rivering.

Is there any way to have a completion suggester on an existing field? Even if it means reindexing data that's fine. For example, when I want to keep the original not_analysed text, I can do something like this in the mappings :

```
"JobTitle": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "Original": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do with the suggesters?

If not, is it possible to do a non whitespace tokenizing/N-Gram search instead to get these fields? While it would be slower, I assume that would work.

Comment: Here is a blog post we did about this issue: http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams. It's a bit involved. I'll put together a simplified version as an answer.

Comment: Hmm so basically NGram searching.. It's a shame, since apparently Suggesters are a lot faster. But I'm fine going down that route.

Comment: Have you tried [prefix query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)? I was about to start an answer with that. It's easy to use, though it may not scale as well as ngrams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here is the easy way that (may or) may not scale, using [prefix queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html).

I'll create an index using the `"fields"` technique you mentioned, and some handy job description data I found [here](https://jobmob.co.il/blog/funny-craigslist-job-titles-listings/):

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"experienced bra fitter", "desc":"I bet they had trouble finding candidates for this one."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"PlayStation Brand Ambassador", "desc":"please report to your residence in the United States of Nintendo."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Eyebrow Threading", "desc":"I REALLY hope this has something to do with dolls."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Administraive/ Secretary", "desc":"ok, ok, we get it. It’s clear where you need help."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Finish Carpenter", "desc":"for when the Start Carpenter gets tired."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Helpdesk Technician @ Pentagon", "desc":"“Uh, hello? I’m having a problem with this missile…”"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Nail Tech", "desc":"so nails can be pretty complicated…"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Remedy Engineer", "desc":"aren’t those called “doctors”?"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Saltlick Cashier", "desc":"new trend in the equestrian industry. Ok, enough horsing around."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Molecular Biologist II", "desc":"when Molecular Biologist I gets promoted."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Breakfast Sandwich Maker", "desc":"we also got one of these recently."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Hotel Housekeepers", "desc":"why can’t they just say ‘hotelkeepers’?"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Preschool Teacher #4065", "desc":"either that’s a really big school or they’ve got robot teachers."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"glacéau drop team", "desc":"for a new sport at the Winter Olympics: ice-water spilling."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"PLUMMER/ELECTRICIAN", "desc":"get a dictionary/thesaurus first."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"DoodyCalls Technician", "desc":"they really shouldn’t put down janitors like that."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Golf Staff", "desc":"and here I thought they were called clubs."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Pressure Washers", "desc":"what’s next, heat cleaners?"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Sandwich Artist", "desc":"another “Jesus in my food” wannabe."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Self Storage Manager", "desc":"this is for self storage?"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Qualified Infant Caregiver", "desc":"too bad for all the unqualified caregivers on the list."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Ground Support", "desc":"but there’s just more dirt under there."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Gymboree Teacher", "desc":"the hardest part is not burning your hands sliding down the pole."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"COMMERCIAL space hunter", "desc":"so they did find animals further out in the cosmos? Who knew."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"JOB COACH", "desc":"if they’re unemployed when they get to you, what does that say about them?"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"KIDS KAMP INSTRUCTOR!", "desc":"no spelling ability required."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"POOLS SUPERVISOR", "desc":"“yeah, they’re still wet…”"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"HOUSE MANAGER/TEEN SUPERVISOR", "desc":"see the dictionary under P, for Parent."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"title":"Licensed Seamless Gutter Contractor", "desc":"just sounds bad."}
```

Then I can easily run a prefix query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
           "title": {
              "value": "san"
           }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "mcRfqtwzTyWE7ZNsKFvwEg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Breakfast Sandwich Maker",
               "desc": "we also got one of these recently."
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "fIYV0WOWRe6gfpYy_u2jlg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Sandwich Artist",
               "desc": "another “Jesus in my food” wannabe."
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Or if I want to be more careful about the matches I can use the un-analyzed field:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
           "title.raw": {
              "value": "San"
           }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "fIYV0WOWRe6gfpYy_u2jlg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Sandwich Artist",
               "desc": "another “Jesus in my food” wannabe."
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is the easy way. Ngrams are a bit more involved, but not difficult. I'll add that in another answer in a bit.

Here's the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4e066d051d7dab5fe819264b0f4b26d958d115a9

**EDIT: Ngram version**

Borrowing the analyzers from [this blog post](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) (shameless plug), I can set up the index as follows:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer", 
               "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer", 
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice that I use different analyzers for indexing and for searching; that's important because if the search query is broken up into ngrams we will probably get a lot more hits than we want.

Populating with the same dataset used above, I can query with a simple `match` query to get the results I expect:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "title": "sup"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1.8631258,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "4pcAOmPNSYupjz7lSes8jw",
            "_score": 1.8631258,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Ground Support",
               "desc": "but there’s just more dirt under there."
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "DVFOC6DsTa6eH_a-RtbUUw",
            "_score": 1.8631258,
            "_source": {
               "title": "POOLS SUPERVISOR",
               "desc": "“yeah, they’re still wet…”"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "klleY_bnQ4uFmCPF94sLOw",
            "_score": 1.4905007,
            "_source": {
               "title": "HOUSE MANAGER/TEEN SUPERVISOR",
               "desc": "see the dictionary under P, for Parent."
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/b0e77bb7f05a4527de5ab4345749c793f923794c

Comment: We've decided to go a slightly different direction now. Imagine the job is titled Engineer - Senior. But the user types in Senior. Do we then suggest that they should type "Engineer?", If we are using NGram or Prefix, it's not going to suggest that. So what we are instead going for is using Facets/Aggregation. You do a search for EVERY term that they enter, and then you return a facet based on title. From there, you filter the facets based on prefix of the LAST word they typed. So if they typed in "Senior Eng", we would still recommend they type "Engineer" based off "Engineer - Senior".

Comment: I'll mark yours as correct, because it definitely fits with my question that I first asked. Now I just have to work out how to filter FACETS before they end up in the payload :)